# Show that the relation R consisting of all pairs (x, y) such...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the relation R consisting of all pairs (x, y) such that x and y are bit strings of length three or more that agree in their first three bits is an equivalence relation on the set of all bit strings of length three or more.

I am new to this kind of math, and what I am stuck at is how do I convert (x,y) into strings of bits?

Thus far I have made the sets: R = {(x,x), (x, y), (y, x), (y, y)} but I need to make them into strings of length three or more. Do I just pick random 1's and 0's???

Comment: Your relation consists of pairs of bit strings. You must show that this relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive to show that it is an equivalence relation. The variables $x$ and $y$ are just symbols used to represent the bit strings in the definition of $R$.

Comment: Ah, so I dont do R ={(x,x), (x, y), (y, x), (y, y)}, but instead I write 2 bit strings of 3 bits and then check if they are equivalence ?

Comment: You have to be more general than two specific bit strings. You can't say, for example, $111=111$ so $R$ is reflexive. You must say something like, if $x$ is any bit string that has at least three bits then its first three bits equal the first three bits of itself so it is Reflexive. Does that make sense?

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding the problem. But imma try and give it a go and return if/when I get stuck, then perhaps u maybe can give a solution?

Comment: I can give you a hint: this is a really easy problem once you understand what's required. If you don't understand what's required, you may want to consider asking different questions.

Comment: Reflexive: x=x
 y=y 
They are both reflexive. 
Symmetric: x=y=x 
It is not symmetric. 
So it is not an equivalence relation.

No point checking for transivity as it is not symmetric. I really have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: Reflexive is $xRx$ that reads: "x is a bit string of length three or more that agree in the first three bits with x". This is true for sure...

Comment: Symmetric is: if $xRy, then $yRx". Again, read it: "if x and y are bit strings of length three or more that agree in their first three bits, then y and x..."

Comment: Then y and x must be bit strings of length three or more that agree in their first three bits. THANKS! 

What about the last one?

Answer (score 1):

Reflexive: $x R x$ for all $x$.
Clearly $x$ and $x$ share the same 3 starting bits as they are the same bit string. Therefore the reflexive property is satisfied.

Symmetric: if $x R y$ then $y R x$: Now if $x$ shares the same first the 3 bit as $y$, then clearly $y$ shares the same first 3 as $x$. Symmetric property is satisfied.

Transitive: if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $xRz$. Let $x,y$ be bit strings that share the same first 3 bits, similarly, $y,z$ are bit strings that share the same first 3 bits. It is clear that if $x$ and $y$ share the same first 3 bits, and if $y$ and $z$ share the same first 3 bits, then $x$ and $z$ must share the same first three bits

We have now proved that the relation $R$ is an equivalence relation.

**Example**

Let's take an example to visualize. Take any 3 bit strings such that they share the same first 3 bits.

Let $x = 101110...$, $y = 101011...$, $z = 101000..$.

Now we can visually see that $xRx$ is clearly true as $x$ and $x$ share the same first 3 bits.

We can also see that symmetric property holds.

Lastly, we can see that if $x$ has the same first 3 bits as $y$ and $y$ has the same first 3 bits as $z$ then $x$ and $z$ share the same first 3

Hope this helps. I know it can be quite confusing!

Comment: Wow thanks man, this helped alot!!! No idea about z, because it was not mentioned.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped :)